# How to find out which script is running at what particular time in unix?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

in my application server,some files are getting deleted from one folder exactly at 1 am everyday.i have checked the crontab.wms file and there is no script which runs at 1 am.
How to find out which script is deleting the files.

Comment: Have you checked all users' crontab?

Comment: Schedule a script to run between 12:55 AM to 1:05 AM.  In that script put a sleep of 10 seconds and collect the output of ps -ef which will list all the processes running during that time.  Next day you can check the logs.  Remember to append to log everytime and not overwrite.

Comment: Are you interested in a Linux-specific solution ?

Comment: Would using some daemon that uses `inotify` technology to monitor the directory help?  Would there be any benefit to creating a script that runs at 00:55 and creates a second directory and hard links every file from the victim directory into the second directory, and another that runs at 01:05 that moves all the files from the second directory (that have only one link?) back to the victim directory.  Basically, all the deletion to occur, but protect the files from deletion by giving them a second name and then restoring the files.

Comment: Also consider whether process accounting can help...a track of all the processes executed during the 00:55-01:05 interval (or any other appropriate time frame).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly 1AM makes cron a prime suspect, but processes can be launched from other places (e.g. init). Also, if the directory can be mounted elsewhere then your server may not be deleting the files. And if malware is causing this, the origin of the process could be intentionally hidden. Some information about where the files are and what the files are could be useful clues.

Repeatedly running ps -aef for several seconds may uncover the culprit. I would run it hundreds of times without sleeping between starting just before 1AM. There can be a lot of processes to examine.

You may also repeatedly run this:

```
/usr/sbin/lsof +d <fullNameOfTheDirectory>
```

to list processes that have opened the specific directory (or files in the directory). This could give a more concise list, but you have to be lucky to be probing at exactly the time the process is using the directory. You may need to try over many nights and you will want both ps and lsof.

If the files do not belong to root, you can chown root  before 1AM. If the delete succeeds then you know the process is root.

I assume the deletion is messing you up. You can archive the files before 1AM and restore them when they go missing, assuming the files are fairly static. Or, you can remove write permissions for a few minutes to see if that thwarts the process (you should still see it accessing the directory). These are kludges, but could patch things up until you can really solve it.

Comment: IS there any way to find out if there is some script which is intentionally hidden and which is deleting the files?